# Pusher - user authentication in presence channels

Tags: javascript, pusher

Is there any way to get the current members of a channel when authenticating a user server-side for a presence channel in Pusher?

I need this to check if the user already subscribed to the channel, so a user can't connect from two browser tabs. Is this doable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query the existing users on a presence channel via the REST API:
http://pusher.com/docs/server_api_guide/interact_rest_api#presence-users (bottom of page)

*Note: If you give a user the same `user_id` as part of the [authentication process](http://pusher.com/docs/authenticating_users#implementing_presence_endpoints) then this will stop the user being shown twice in a presence channel even if they are connected via two tabs. This is because Pusher uses the `user_id` as a unique ID so won't count the subscription as a new user joining the channel.*

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to return a message to the user from my server when authenticating? pusher:subscription_error fires, but it says "invalid auth response ..." when I return a json with my error message for the user.

Comment: All that you can do by the looks of it is send a specific non-200 HTTP status code that you can check in your app and act accordingly (e.g. [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper_Text_Coffee_Pot_Control_Protocol) or something more appropriate :) ). See [the pusher-js auth callback code](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-js/blob/master/src/pusher_authorizer.js#L65) and [docs](http://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_events#subscription_error) for more info.